# Positioning elements within Classes outside of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am using this demo plugin here http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PrettySimpleContentSlider/ and am trying to get the the animated tabs (ul id="rotmenu") on the right to be able to float freely and be posistioned freely outside of its main div class "rotator," and still maintain its functionality and play its part within rotator.  I've tried to do some simple changes here and there with attributes of divs and classes but they have just messed things up more or less. any ideas?

Okay here is the js using the jquery_easing.1.3 and jquery.min.js libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var current = 1;

            var iterate     = function(){
                var i = parseInt(current+1);
                var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();

            }
            display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
            var slidetime = setInterval(iterate,3000);

            $('#rotmenu li').bind('click',function(e){
                clearTimeout(slidetime);
                display($(this));
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            function display(elem){
                var $this   = elem;
                var repeat  = false;
                if(current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
                    repeat = true;

                if(!repeat)
                    $this.parent().find('li:nth-child('+current+') a').stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'-20px'},300,function(){
                        $(this).animate({'opacity':'0.7'},700);
                    });

                current = parseInt($this.index() + 1);

                var elem = $('a',$this);

                    elem.stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'0px','opacity':'1.0'},300);

                var info_elem = elem.next();
                $('#rot1 .heading').animate({'left':'-420px'}, 500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                    $('h1',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
                    $(this).animate({'left':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                });

                $('#rot1 .description').animate({'bottom':'-270px'},500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                    $('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
                    $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                })
                $('#rot1').prepend(
                $('<img/>',{
                    style   :   'opacity:0',
                    className : 'bg'
                }).load(
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
                    $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({'opacity':'0'},700,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }
              ).attr('src','images/'+info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width','800').attr('height','300')
            );
            }
        });
    </script>
```

where the jquery is applied

```
 <body>
    <div id="content">
        <a class="back" href=""></a>

        <div class="rotator">
            <ul id="rotmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="rot1">Portfolio</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">1.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Our Works</div>
                        <div class="info_description">

                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot2">Services</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We serve</div>
                        <div class="info_description">

                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot3">Contact</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">3.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Get in touch</div>
                        <div class="info_description">

                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot4">Experiments</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">4.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We do crazy stuff</div>
                        <div class="info_description">

                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot5">Applications</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">5.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Working things</div>
                        <div class="info_description">

                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="rot1">
                <img src="" width="800" height="300" class="bg" alt=""/>
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p></p>

                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can't tell what your problem is without seeing your code. A demo in jsfiddle.net would also help

Comment: okay. ive included the jqurey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be visible outside of its parent (`.rotator`) you need to change the parent's CSS to have `overflow: visible`. Then you can position the `#rotmenu` wherever you want.

```
#rotmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}    
.rotator {
    ...
    overflow:visible;
    ...
}
```

In addition, in order to continue masking the animated components, you need to set `#rot1` to overflow: hidden and make it have the same dimensions as the common parent (`.rotator`).

```
#rot1 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Finally, just to prevent broken images from collecting in the DOM (which happens in the example, because we don't include the source images), I added an error handler to the image insertion code to remove the image.

```
$('#rot1').prepend(
$('<img/>', {
    style: 'opacity:0',
    className: 'bg'
}).error(function () {
    $(this).remove();
}).load(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 600);
    $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 700, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}).attr('src', 'images/' + info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width', '800').attr('height', '300'));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hK43c/)

Comment: I tried this idea earlier but now whenever I click one of the tabs it adds space in the y-axis direction and allows for scrolling into nothingness.

Comment: @user1325578 I updated my answer and example to prevent the issue you were seeing and to hide the other animated elements from being visible outside of the content area.

Answer (score 1):

first of all it sounds to me like you think because rotmenu is part of rotator class, that you need to have the rotator class outside of it. that is not how class works. if you want rotmenu to be part of that class do . if that is not the case, then ignore this part of the message.

the way it is structure is that your unordered list is wrapped by some invisible div. i dont know what you mean specifically by messing up. but it may have something to do with some css elements of that wrapper div due to its class.